# WatchKit: Difference between push and modal segue? No page navigation with push?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I am experimenting with watchkit and realize the some difference between push and modal segue.

When using modal segue and add page navigation, it works fine. But with push segue and add page navigation in the second InterfaceController, the page navigation is not showing. Anyone know why?

If you think about this, modal feels more like joining the hierarchical tree for the 1st Interface controller. But push is creating another InterfaceController. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presenting a controller using pushControllerWithName does not work with page-based navigation.